# What is the toolchain to be used to compile Berkeley bootloader (bbl)?

Tags: riscv, rocket-chip

I have to run riscv-tests and SPEC2006 on riscv-linux (booted) on FPGA. I would like to know what is the compilation toolchain to be used for this flow.

I understand that riscv-linux has to be compiled with riscv64-linux-gcc. However, I'm unclear that about riscv-tests. Can riscv-elf-gcc be used to compile riscv-tests and run on riscv-linux? I read some of the posted mentioned in stackoverflow about SPEC2006 and bbl (both compiled with riscv-linux-gcc). I want to run riscv-tests also. Should they also be compiled with (riscv-linux-gcc) ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compile **bbl** or **baremetal** applications like **riscv-tests** you should you  `riscv64-unknown-elf-` or `riscv32-unknown-elf-` *(with Newlib)* .

Because `riscv64-linux` contains more libraries that make compilation process complicated.We mainly use **riscv64-linux**  to compile application that run on **riscv-linux**.